# beginAtZero not working on mixed chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to make a chart with multiple lines and bars but they need to start at 0 and it works fine for the bar's but not one the lines.
I tried setting a id for the options setting options in the dataset but nothings works

Here is my code:

```
            <canvas id="barLine" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

@section('js')
    @parent
    <script>
        var ctx = document.getElementById("barLine");
        new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: ['contacten', 'orders', 'logistiek'],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Aantal',
                    data: [5.3, 5.5, 5.7],
                    backgroundColor: colors,
                    borderColor: colors,
                    borderWidth: 1
                }, {
                    label: 'Aantal',
                    data: [5.7, 6.5, 6],
                    backgroundColor: colors,
                    borderColor: colors,
                    borderWidth: 1
                }, {
                    label: 'Aantal',
                    data: [7.8, 5, 7],
                    backgroundColor: colors,
                    borderColor: colors,
                    borderWidth: 1
                }, {
                    label: 'Target 2016',
                    data: [5.0, 5.0, 5.0],
                    type: 'line',
                    fill: false,
                    pointHitRadius: 10,
                    pointRadius: 0,
                    pointStyle: 'rect'
                }, {
                    label: 'Target 2017',
                    data: [7.5, 7.5, 7.5],
                    type: 'line',
                    fill: false,
                    pointHitRadius: 10,
                    pointRadius: 0,
                    pointStyle: 'rect'
                }, {
                    label: 'Target 2018',
                    data: [7, 7, 7],
                    type: 'line',
                    fill: false,
                    pointHitRadius: 10,
                    pointRadius: 0,
                    pointStyle: 'rect',
                    backgroundColor:'purple',
                    borderColor:'purple',
                    beginAtZero:true
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            max: 10,
                            min: 0
                        },
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: "Cijfer"
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
@stop
```

So it needs to work that the lines (target 2016......) need to start at 0. I can make it work with just a line but with mixed I cannot make it so.

Answer (score 0):

beginAtZero is an attribute of ticks so you need to put it inside ticks, which is part of options:

```
options:{
    scales:{
         yAxes:[{
             ticks:{
                 beginAtZero: true
             }
         }]
    }
}
```